# <no devices>devices not detected in VSCode & android studio using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, adb

How to fix device not detected?

```
    adb devices
    List of devices attached
    42001d159ac454  device


    flutter doctor 
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 5.4.0-124-generic,
        locale en_US.UTF-8)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    [✓] VS Code
    [✓] Connected device (1 available)
    [✓] HTTP Host Availability
    
    • No issues found!
```

Everything is normal when checked by `flutter doctor`.

[image: android studio]
[image: vs code]

Comment: Check your system if you have multiple versions of `adb.exe` installed. This situation can occur if the active adb instance is an old/outdated version of adb so that the IDE can not communicate with adb.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on emulator in android studio, wiping data solves the problem

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Export sdk path to environment variables

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Comment: I have configured it, but it doesn't work